# The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component, Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm trying to use a `react-router`, after using the library some problems begin, I've already tried to write different code, I found it ready-made on the Internet, but still something is wrong (even reset Windows). This code is taken from the official react-router documentation, did everything as written (https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation)
Here is the errors:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. >This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
>    printWarning @ react.development.js:207

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
>
> at useRef (react.development.js:1628:1)
>
> at BrowserRouter (index.tsx:151:1)
>
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
>
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
>
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
>
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
>
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
>
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
>
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
>
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)

> The above error occurred in the  component:
>
> at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:45400:5)
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
> Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
> logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18572

4 errors with `invalid hooks`, 3 errors with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')` and `The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component` appear in the console once

Here is my code:

`src/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`src./App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Routes,Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to React Router!</h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <h2>Welcome to the homepage!</h2>
        <p>You can do this, I believe in you.</p>
      </main>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

function About() {
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <h2>Who are we?</h2>
        <p>
          That feels like an existential question, don't you
          think?
        </p>
      </main>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

and `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ao-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test", 
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I did everything as it is written in the documentation (https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation)

Comment: That is a *really* old version of `create-react-app`. Try using v4 or newer. Are you using `npx` to run the create app command, i.e. `npx create-react-app <your app name here>`?

Comment: code works fine, try updating your dependencies.

Comment: @DrewReese, 
before that, I also formed the application through npx create-react-app (with the old version). I downloaded version 5 of create-react-app, even re-created it, it still doesn't work, can the error appear due to the fact that I'm not using webpack? 
Forgot to say that the error with invalid hook calls appears in the console 4 times, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') 3 times and The above error occurred in the component once

Comment: I'm pretty certain that `create-react-app` shouldn't be installed as a project dependency. It shouldn't even be installed locally in npm. Do you have this code available in a public repo we could inspect and run, or can you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese, Everything works in codesandbox, I made exactly the same code as in my project. I don’t understand at all what’s wrong, maybe I’m somehow installing the packages wrong? Here is a link to codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-parm-kv3d87?file=/src/App.js   Created a project like this:
(I work in VScode)
1) Created a folder
2) Through the terminal (built in VScode) I prescribe npm i create-react-app@5
3) npm i react
4) npm i react-dom
5) npm i react-router
6) npm i react-router-dom
7) Next, I create a react app using npx create-react-app <mнName> and write the code

Comment: @DrewReese, Now again I created a new project according to the same principle and noticed that after npm i create-react-app@5, I see in the terminal:

Comment: `PS C:\Users\DaFu4\OneDrive\Desktop\router> npm i create-react-app@5
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
added 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 4s
4 packages are looking for funding                                                                                                     
3 high severity vulnerabilities  
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
Run npm audit for details.`

Comment: maybe the problem in 3 high severity vulnerabilities?

Comment: Why are you installing `create-react-app` at all? It's meant to be run using `npx` which will use the current version available. See [quick start guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#quick-start). Just run `npx create-react-app <mhName>` then `cd` into the newly created directory and run `npm i` to install the dependencies, then `npm i -s react-router` to install it, then you should be able to run `npm start`.

Comment: @DrewReese, Did as you said:
1) created a folder
2) npx create-react-app <myName>
3) npm i -s react-router
4) npm i -s react-router-dom
5) cd <myName>
6)npm start

The errors are still the same, except that package.json has changed:

Comment: @DrewReese, does not fit in a comment, now I will post the entire folder on gitHub

Comment: @DrewReese, (Changed the post itself)

Comment: @DrewResse, I solved the problem, in the end I'm a fool. The problem was that I downloaded the library not to the project itself, but to the folder with the project, which is why I had package.json inside the project and in the folder itself, in which the react router was installed, that is, before downloading the library, I forgot go to the project itself via cd <myName>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that I downloaded the library not to the project itself, but to the project folder, which is why I had package.json inside the project and in the project folder itself, in which the react-router was installed, that is, before downloading the library I forgot to go to the project itself via cd

Comment: you are genius dude, saved a lot of time. Thanks big time

Comment: same mistake here :p

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue. Just uninstall the version 6 of the react-router-dom and install it like

> `npm i react-router-dom`

This worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I tested all above, but this below worked for me:

```
npm install --save react-router-dom@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing `react-router-dom` using `npm i react-router-dom` just restart the app
in my case, I solved it this way